# ERROR: root is missing the Job/Create permission

Tags: jenkins

I got a problem when I use jenkins cli to create a job.

```
jenkins java -jar  $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/after-merge-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/lib/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ create-job  Merged-mobile-android-nova-sku-release-9.2.6-0 < ~/config/Merged-mobile-android-nova-sku-release-9.2.6-0.xml
```

> ERROR: root is missing the Job/Create permission

How to solve this?