# Jenkins Build Pipeline View- user is missing the Job/Create permission

Tags: jenkins

My user is not Admin, but has been granted all the Job permissions. In the permissions page, my user has all the boxes checked under the "Jobs" section; Including the Job/Create permission.

I'm working on a View. And the "Select initial job" is set to the job I want, but doesn't show up in the actual view. So I try to "Add Step" button:

[image]

But I still get the `Access Denied: user is missing the Job/Create permission`. And no step showing up in the View.

This article is the only thing I could find, but it doesn't solve the problem, the version of the Cloudbees Folder plugin I'm using is greater than that recommended version. [cloudbees support ticket](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/231184347-RBAC-Folders-User-is-missing-the-Job-Create-permission)

This question is unanswered: [ERROR: root is missing the Job/Create permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341797/error-root-is-missing-the-job-create-permission)

## Question

How do I resolve this permission issue?